# Unwanted <p> tags are stored in bodytext for tt_content table

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

Some days ago I discovered that my TYPO3 development installation of the 9.5.1 version stores the paragraph tag for the bodytext in tt_content table:

```
<p>my text</p>
```

So this tag is also visible in the frontend:

```
<p>&lt;p&gt;my text&lt;/p&gt;<p>
```

In older content element there is no p tag stored:

```
my text
```

If I edit an old content element the p tag is added in database.

I defined no RTE PageTS and lib.parseFunc_RTE is untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem: I moved the inclusion of TypoScript from fluid_styled_content from the template record into my site package setup.typoscript file - but forgot to include also the constants. After adding it to constants.typoscript of my site package extension the unwanted p tags are gone.